# How to change the grey scale value of a region in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am new to Python and not really sure how to attack this problem.

What I am trying to do is to take a black and white image and change the value of the edge (x pixels thick) from 255 to some other greyscale value.

I need to do this to a set of png images inside of a folder. All images will be geometric (mostly a combination of straight lines) no crazy curves or patterns. Using Python 3.

Please check the images.

[image: Original 1]

[image: Desired 1]

[image: Original 2]

[image: Desired 2]

A typical file will look like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13ls1pikNsO7ZbsHatC6cOr4O6Fj0MPOZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The comments should explain pretty well what I going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from skimage.morphology import dilation, square

# Open input image and ensure it is greyscale
image = Image.open('XYbase.png').convert('L')

# Find the edges
edges = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)

# Convert edges to Numpy array and dilate (fatten) with our square structuring element
selem = square(6)
fatedges = dilation(np.array(edges),selem)

# Make Numpy version of our original image and set all fatedges to brightness 128
imnp = np.array(image)
imnp[np.nonzero(fatedges)] = 128

# Convert Numpy image back to PIL image and save
Image.fromarray(imnp).save('result.png')
```

So, if I start with this image:

[image]

The (intermediate) edges look like this:

[image]

And I get this as the result:

[image]

---

If you want the outlines fatter/thinner, increase/decrease the `6` in:

```
selem = square(6)
```

If you want the outlines lighter/darker, increase/decrease the `128` in:

```
imnp[np.nonzero(fatedges)] = 128
```

---

**Keywords**: image, image processing, fatten, thicken, outline, trace, edge, highlight, Numpy, PIL, Pillow, edge, edges, morphology, structuring element, skimage, scikit-image, erode, erosion, dilate, dilation.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I realized I did not ask my question properly. The image will not always be a square. Sometimes it will also be am L-shape image. I edited the original post to show it.

Comment: Actually, I think you have done me in again! The sample image you give in Google drive **already has** a grey border around the shapes - unlike the ones you show in the question which don't already have a border. The code is written assuming no initial grey border around the white shapes.

Comment: Haha sorry. I did upload the wrong image. Thank you very much Mark, this was pretty much what I needed. I just had to change it a bit and add the code for batch process. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Cool - glad we got there in the end. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret your question in a much simpler way, so I thought I'd answer that simpler question too. Maybe you already have a grey-ish edge around your shapes (like the Google drive files you shared) and just want to change all pixels that are neither black nor white into a different colour - and the fact that they are edges is irrelevant. That is much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open input image and ensure it is greyscale
image = Image.open('XYBase.png').convert('L')

# Make Numpy version
imnp = np.array(image)

# Set all pixels that are neither black nor white to 220
imnp[(imnp>0) & (imnp<255)] = 220

# Convert Numpy image back to PIL image and save
Image.fromarray(imnp).save('result.png')
```