# How to detect a specific border detail of an image and crop according to it using python and PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, crop, object-detection

I'm currently trying to crop an image by detecting the 2 big black corners on the upper-right and lower-left pf the document: http://www.suiteexpert.fr/AideProd/SalaireExpert/Images/Editions/aemapercu.png
I'm trying to find a simpler method than deep-learning OCR for better performance.

I have tried a few different things such as detecting a change in color, by starting along the edges of the document and detecting a change from white to black. This seems to work but it first detects the very small vertical text on some of the image examples: https://www.movinmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AEM-V5-MM-.jpg

This also leeds to other problems due to the fact that the documents I want to analyze could also be in different colors, and could also be scans or photographs.

However, these documents will always have the same internal shape and structure (it's a standardized administrative document).

I would want some of your feedback as to how I could detect the 2 big black corners on the upper right and lower left corners of the document, which would allow me process and normalize the image by rotating and cropping it.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def trim(im, border):
     bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, border)
     diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
     bbox = diff.getbbox()
     if bbox:
         return im.crop(bbox)
     else:
         # found no content
         raise ValueError("cannot trim; image was empty")
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As you stated *"these documents will always have the same internal shape and structure "*, so you may try getting the coordinates of the two black corners and then do a crop via them. My approach is that, as you stated that same internal shape/format would be used in every document, so their sizes/frame would also be same. And if they are then cropping might be the way to go

Comment: Well the internal structure of the document is the same, and by this I mean what is inside the 2 black corners. But the margins of empty space on the edges of the document may vary. This is why I can't just use the coordinates of the 2 black corners as they will not always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got time to write this up in Python at the moment, but if you follow these steps you can do it:

- do a *"morphological closing"* with a rectangular 5x5 structuring element to get rid of the thin lines around the edge (and everywhere else)
- trim the image to get rid of excess white borders around the edges

I did it with **ImageMagick** in Terminal like this:

```
convert form.png -threshold 50% -morphology close rectangle:5 -trim result.png
```

and then sneakily added a red border just so you can see the extent of the image on Stack Overflow's white background:

[image]

In Python, use `skimage` to do the morphology - it'll look like these lines:

```
# Convert edges to Numpy array and dilate (fatten) with our square structuring element
selem = square(6)
fatedges = dilation(np.array(edges),selem)
```

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119204/2836621), except you will need `binary_closing()` in place of `dilation()` - see [documentation here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.binary_closing).

You can then do the trimming with PIL/Pillow's [Image.getbbox()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html). Of course, you apply the trim box to a clean copy of your original image, not the morphologically altered one :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also look for the `L`shape at top-right using *"Hit-or-Miss morphology"*. You define a shape that must **hit** the image and also a shape that must **miss** the image and it tells you where both cases are true. Documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_hit_or_miss.html).

If we zoom in on the top-right `L` shape till you can count the individual pixels, you will see the horizontal bar of the `L` is around 18x6 pixels:

[image]

So,

```
import scipy as sp 
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
form=cv2.imread('form.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# We are going to do Hit-or-Miss morphology, define structuring elements
hit = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.int) 
hit[:,-4:]=1
hit[:4,:]=1
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Now define what we must miss:

```
miss = np.zeros_like(hit)
miss[-4:,:4]=1
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Now apply the Hit-or-Miss:

```
res = sp.ndimage.binary_hit_or_miss(1-(form.astype(np.bool)),structure1=hit,structure2=miss)                                                                                          

cv2.imwrite('result.png',res*255)
```

[image]

Hopefully, you can see a white dot at top-right where this pattern was found.

The nett effect of the morphological processing is that we are looking for a shape that matches this, where `B` represents black, `W` represents white and `X` means *"don't care"*:

```
B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B
X, X, X, X, X, X, B, B, B, B
X, X, X, X, X, X, B, B, B, B
W, W, W, W, X, X, B, B, B, B
W, W, W, W, X, X, B, B, B, B
W, W, W, W, X, X, B, B, B, B
W, W, W, W, X, X, B, B, B, B
```

---

Then repeat with the transposed shape to look for the `L` shape in bottom-left.

**Keywords**: Python, skimage, scikit-image, shape detection, morphology, morphological, Hit-or-miss, hit or miss, don't care, hit miss, image, image processing.